# Windows gives error with package.json file

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I wanted my Package.json to be something like this

```
{
  "name": "Billing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.2",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-handlebars": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.8.1"
  }
}
```

I tried this using `npm install` but got this error

> package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

So I used command line to create json, and added dependencies. What I found was that most of the packages were installed without giving this errors, and also my package.json got updated correctly by using `npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev` and so on.

On Windows I am seeing this error only for two packages: for grunt-contrib-uglify" as well as grunt-contrib-handlebars. So my JSON file is ending with

```
{
  "name": "Billing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.2",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You must be getting additional info about the error. Please add that. These lines begin with `npm ERR!`.

Comment: npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\zm2759\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\wordwrap\0.0.2\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "grunt-contrib-uglify" "--save-dev"

Comment: npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\zm2759\Desktop\GruntJS
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! file C:\Users\zm2759\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\wordwrap\0.0.2\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zm2759\Desktop\GruntJS\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like there is an error in your package.json. The one in `C:\Users\zm2759\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\wordwrap\0.0.2\package\package.json`. Since it is inside npm-cache, I believe you can clear it with `npm cache clean`.

Otherwise there seems to be no problem with your own `package.json`.